# Batik dependency not working in Payara for version 4.1.2.173

Tags: glassfish, batik, payara

I have a jsf project which uses the `batik-bridge 1.6-1` dependency.
When I run the project on glassfish 4.1.1 it works perfectly but when I use Payara 4.1.2.173 I obtain this error stack

```
 Grave:   org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.setFeature(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.setFeatures(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParserImpl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.setFeature(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.XMLHelper.createParserFactory(XMLHelper.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceXML(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceArchive(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:617)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.getPersistenceUnits(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfoInArchive(JPAInitializer.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfoInArchives(JPAInitializer.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfo(JPAInitializer.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:188)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
   ...
```

this the part of code which produces the error:

```
    @Stateless
    public class MyEventListener extends DescriptorEventAdapter {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = StaticUtil.UNIT_NAME)
    private EntityManager em;

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        EntityManagerFactory entityFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(StaticUtil.UNIT_NAME);
        em = (JpaEntityManager) entityFactory.createEntityManager();
        return em;

    }
...
```

The persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    
    <persistence-unit name="mypersistence-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>myJNDI</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.jpa.uppercase-column-names" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/> 
<!--            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINEST"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="ServerLogger"/>-->
            <!--<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>-->
            <!--<property name="eclipselink.logging.level.cache" value="FINE"/>-->
            <!--property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/-->
            <!--property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/-->
            <!--<property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>-->
            <!--property name="eclipselink.logging.level.cache" value="FINEST"/-->
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
            <!--<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**NB**:When I remove the `Batik-bridge 1.6-1` dependency the project works both in Payara & glassfish but I need this dependency

Comment: Batik depends on xercesImpl and it seems that EclipseLink subsystem in JPA picks it up to read persistence.xml instead of using internal SAXParser. The error is that the xerces SAX parser cannot parse persistence.xml. Can you post contents of persistence.xml?

Comment: @OndrejM I added it in the question

Comment: @OndrejM i found the solution you can check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was solved with upgrading to Batik 1.7, must use this dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

instead:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>batik</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
            <version>1.6-1</version> 
        </dependency>
```

As @OndrejM said the batik 1.6-1 depends on xercesImpl which causes the probleme with the Sax parser seems that Batik 1.7 uses another parser, now it works perfectly